# Is there a delete trigger called on deleting an html file?

Tags: windows, html

How is it that when I delete the file, say `Stack Overflow.htm`, the folder `Stack Overflow_files` is automatically deleted along with it? And does this user have control over this?

Strictly talking for Windows because this behavior is not to be found on a *nix system.

Comment: @Renan try saving the a webpage from the browser(Firefox) then delete the `*.htm`

Comment: Did it. The htm file was gone. The folder remained.

Comment: @Renan I had this observation on almost every Windows I tried it on. On Windows ME too, if I am not mistakened.